# How does one split large result set from a Group By into multiple flat files?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm far away from an SSIS expert and I'm attempting to correct an error (unspecified in the messages) that began once I modified a variable to increase the size of the data accumulated and exported into a flat file. (Note variable was a date in the WHERE statement that limited the data returned from the SELECT.)

So in the data flow there's a GROUP BY component and I'm trying to find the appropriate component to put in between that and the flat file destination component to chop up the results. I figured there'd be something to export, say flatFile1.csv, flatFile2.csv, etc. based on a number of lines (so if I set a limit of 1-million lines and the results returned 3.5-million, I'd get 4 files with the last one containing 1/2-million lines) or perhaps a max file size with similar results.

Which component should I use from the toolbox to guarantee a manageable file size?

Is a script component the only way to be able to handle any size output? If so would it sit in between the Group By and the Flat File output components or would the script completely obviate the need for the Flat File output?

Comment: Add a derived column to add a rownumber and then a conditional split where @rn<1M @rn<2M and so on

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I'd have to assume how many potential files and hard-code that in? I.e. if the number of records ever goes beyond a certain number I'd have to add another file and redeploy the package.

Comment: You are correct. Personally, I'd do it in a script component. But that explanation does not include the usage of "out of the box" objects that you requested.

Comment: I'd consider it a solution - a script component is one of the objects proposed (just need some code in there).

Comment: Edited my question to reflect this...